# Comparison of coefficients within one regression

Tags: regression-coefficients

I am running a multiple regression model based on panel data that investigates the effect of different types of firm ownership on a certain dependent variable (OLS-estimators). The two independent variables of interest are both in a percentage form, thus have the same scale (think of it as share of ownership category A and B)

The regression equation is therefore as follows:

$$Y= \beta_0 + \beta_1*\text{Share_ownershipcategoryA} + \beta_2*\text{Share_ownershipcategoryB} + 
\text{Controlvariables} + u$$

The estimated $\hat{\beta}_1$ is slightly higher than $\hat{\beta}_2$. 
Now I would like to test whether or not the difference between the two categories of ownership is indeed significant; thus if ownership of category A is really better than category B.

Can I just use the normal test as indicated below?

$$\frac{\hat{\beta}_1 - \hat{\beta}_2}{\sqrt{SE(\hat{\beta}_1)^2+SE(\hat{\beta}_2)^2}}$$

I would have argued yes since both estimates are based on the same sample, have the same error term and are of the same scale. Nevertheless, I am not sure and my web search could not provide the necessary evidence.
If I am wrong with my suggestion, is there an alternative to execute such a test.

Thank you for your time and your feedback!

Comment: It looks like a typical ANCOVA problem, so please refer to relevant references/wikipedia. The formula you gave is incorrect. Also, the term "normal test" doesn't look like a conventional one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\hat{\beta}_1$ and $\hat{\beta}_2$  are likely dependent, your test statistic ought to be

$$\frac{\hat{\beta}_1 - \hat{\beta}_2}{\sqrt{Var(\hat{\beta}_1-\hat{\beta}_2)}}=
\frac{\hat{\beta}_1 - \hat{\beta}_2}{\sqrt{Var(\hat{\beta}_1)+Var(\hat{\beta}_2) - Cov(\hat{\beta}_1,\hat{\beta}_2)}}$$

which will be compared to a $t$-distribution with $n-p$ degrees of freedom. You may compare this to a $t$-distribution because a linear combination of Normal random variables (which the $\hat{\beta}$ estimates asymptotically are) is still Normal and you have unknown variance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your post. It makes sense for me that the two coefficients might be correlated with each other and the correspondig formula should be used. So the application of an ANCOVA analysis as suggested above is not required?

Is it possible to calculate the corresponding covariance term in STATA? Or can I just use the F-Test command and test for the difference?

I am sorry for the nooby questions, I am far away from being a Pro.